# Returning promises in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need some help returning a promise. I don't get why I am not getting the players value

The code

```
const playerSelectName = document.getElementById('sel1');
const playerSelectPosition = document.getElementById('sel2');
const playerSelectAge = document.getElementById('sel3');
const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-btn');

async function getPlayers() {
    const response = await fetch('https://football-players-b31f2.firebaseio.com/players.json?print=pretty');
    const playersObject = await response.json();
    return playersObject;
}

searchButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const players = await getPlayers();
    let [ name, position, age ] = [ playerSelectName.value, playerSelectPosition.value, playerSelectAge.value ];
    yersObject.filter((playerAge) => {});
});
```

I cant get to access the code inside my listener function of the value players

Comment: You don't try in the code provided. Can you clarify what you mean by: _I cant get to access the code inside my listener function of the value players_

Comment: I don't understand either ... the players object returned from `getPlayers()` is called `players` inside of your event listener. But you never actually use `players` there

Comment: Please add the html also so it will be easy to answer the exact solution what you are looking for and also please explain what you are trying to achieve in filter function. So we can help on that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in destructuring check the below snippet. I hope this will solve the issue . Also please update what you are trying to achieve in filter so i can add on the solution.

I didnt understood what are you trying to do in destructure part and after that filter

```js
async function getPlayers() {
    const response = await fetch('https://football-players-b31f2.firebaseio.com/players.json?print=pretty');
    const playersObject = await response.json();
    return playersObject;
}

const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-btn');

searchButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const players = await getPlayers();
    players.forEach(player => {
     const {name, nationality, position} = player
     console.log(name, nationality, position)
    })
    
});
```

```html
<button id='search-btn'>
  Load Results
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example accessing the `players` to help get you started.

```js
async function getPlayers() {
    const response = await fetch('https://football-players-b31f2.firebaseio.com/players.json?print=pretty');
    return response.json();
}

(async () => {
    const players = await getPlayers();
    console.log(players)
})();
```